# How get variable from request in pre-request script?

Tags: postman

1) I set environment variable:

```
   title = "foo-bar"
```

Picture:

[image]

2) I set Request Post parameter

```
title = {{title}}
```

Picture:

[image]

3) I send POST and a need find title in pre-request script:

```
pm.request.body.urlencoded.all().forEach(param=>{
    if(param.key == "title")console.log(param.value);
})
```

But in log : `{{title))` , I need `foo-bar`

I want get title from request, dont from pm.variables.get("title")

Comment: For the `1)` point, That's not how you set an environment variable. What does your request body look like, can you post an image, please.

Comment: The `{{variables}}` syntax used in the body of the request doesn't get populated until runtime so `pm.request.body.urlencoded` wouldn't show the resolved value at that point.

Comment: @DannyDainton 1) Update 2) Its Api. I need calculate hash(sha256) from all POST params in pre request script and set hash in HTTP header.  Some of them (POST params) are in the environment variables and in global variables.